# Retrieve values from a frozen set dictionary (python)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, set, frozenset

I have a frozen set dictionary of the form:

```
{frozenset({12345, 3245}): 45.95948791503906,
 frozenset({12345, 12804138}): 48.996036529541016,
 frozenset({3245, 9876}): 50.67853927612305,
```

Is it possible for me to iterate  over the values based on one of the key from the frozenset?

Example:

If I provide the value 12345, I want to return

```
frozenset({12345, 3245}): 45.95948791503906,
frozenset({12345, 12804138}): 48.996036529541016
```

If I provide the value 3245, I want to return

```
frozenset({12345, 3245}): 45.95948791503906, frozenset({3245, 9876}): 50.67853927612305
```

Basically, I want to iterate based one of the key from the multikey frozen set dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
my_dict = {frozenset({12345, 3245}): 45.95948791503906,
 frozenset({12345, 12804138}): 48.996036529541016,
 frozenset({3245, 9876}): 50.67853927612305}



def retrieve_dict(number_I_want):
  final = []
  for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for i in key:
      if i == number_I_want:
        final.append(key)
  print(final)

retrieve_dict(12345)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do a lot of this, you might want to transform from `{frozenset([k]):v}` to `{k:[(frozenset(), v)]}`. The result is that the answers are all `d[v]`. If you only need to do it a little and need to keep the data in the other form, use the loop in the other answer.

To do this transform:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {frozenset({12345, 3245}): 45.95948791503906,
 frozenset({12345, 12804138}): 48.996036529541016,
 frozenset({3245, 9876}): 50.67853927612305}
o = defaultdict(list)
for p in d.items():
    for k in s[0]:
        o[k].append(p)
```

This results in `dict(o)` being:

```
{3245: [(frozenset([3245, 12345]), 45.95948791503906),
        (frozenset([3245, 9876]), 50.67853927612305)],
 9876: [(frozenset([3245, 9876]), 50.67853927612305)],
 12345: [(frozenset([12345, 12804138]), 48.996036529541016),
         (frozenset([3245, 12345]), 45.95948791503906)],
 12804138: [(frozenset([12345, 12804138]), 48.996036529541016)]}
```